# OpenVidu: is there a way to apply a textoverlay filter showing a unique value on each subscriber screen?

Tags: kurento

Perhaps the subscriber's connectionId or similar. The purpose is to identify subscribers who try to restream videos to unauthorized sites.

Answer (score 0):

Filters may only be applied to Publisher streams, you cannot apply a filter to a Subscriber stream. So all participants subscribed to that Stream will receive the same modified video.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks @Pablo